# Duplicates in vertical axis in the Thingsboard chart

Tags: thingsboard

I am new to Thingsboard.

Today I created a chart to see temperature from a few sensors.

The problem is, I can see a few vertical marks which are the same:
I.e. two pairs of 28, two pairs of 26, etc.

As to me, it is quite strange… Maybe, it was designed this way, and I simply don’t understand why…

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by rounding: By default, the Y-Axis doesn't show decimal values.
In this example, I have 4 Values: `20.1, 19.7, 20, 20` which are all rounded to 20 in the Y-Axis:

[image: Y-Axis with rounding]

If you change the number of decimals displayed in the settings, it works as expected:
[image: Widget settings]

[image: Y-Axis without rounding]